# modifying the value of a non static variable which was initialized with a static variable modifies the static variable as well

Tags: java, android, static

I need help !. I am trying to access the value of a static variable from one class in another class in an android project. This is the static class...

```
public class NamesStore {

  private static NamesStore sNamesStore ;
  private static List<Name> sNames = new ArrayList<>();

  public static NamesStore getInstance() {
    if (sNamesStore == null) {
      return new NamesStore();
    } else {
      return sNamesStore;
    }
  }

  public List<Name> getNames(){
   return sNames;
  }

}
```

now in other class, I try to get the static variable to use the value but modifying it before use like this ...

```
public class Utils{

  public static removeTheseNamesFromTheGeneralNames(List<Name> namesToBeRemoved){
      List<Name> names = NamesStore.getInstance().getNames();
      names.removeAll(namesToBeRemoved);
      return names;
  }

}
```

when I call the method removeTheseNamesFromTheGeneralNames, the static variable in NamesStore is also modified and I can't figure out why.? Is this a normal behavior of a static field? and if so, please how can I copy the value of a static field and modify without changing the value stored in the static field.? I could make it static and final to resolve this but I also need to set that static variable from time to time with a setter method. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The variable is not modified. You are dreaming. The *object* the variable *refers* to is modified, but that's because you modified it. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'static' is not really the core problem here (though it might contribute). The problem is in method `getNames()` and how the result is used by its caller.

In your NamesStore class, there is one list of names (the ArrayList) and there is one reference to that list of names (sNames).

When you execute `return sNames` and the caller assigns the return value to his variable `names`, you still have exactly one list of names (one ArrayList), now with two references to the same list.  This is not a consequence of 'static' but  a consequence of how Java uses reference types; in short, assignment (and returning a value) makes a copy of a reference, it does not make another instance of the thing being referred to.

So, of course, when the list referred to by `names` is modified, that does modify the one and only list of names that exists.

---

If you wish to allow the caller to modify the list returned by your `getNames()` method without modifying your list, then you need to return a copy of your list, not your list itself.

Writing `return new ArrayList<>(sNames)` would do that; but note that only the list of names is copied, whatever is in the list is (presumably 'names') is not. In other words, if your caller modifies an actual name, it will modify the only instance of that name. You need to determine what your requirements are.

An alternative approach is to forbid your user from changing the returned list; that can be implemented as `return Collections.unmodifiableList(sNames)`.  If an attempt is made to change that list then the code doing that change will fail. Anyone who wants to modify the list (as in your example) must make themselves a copy first.

The decision between these two is probably made on the basis of considering how many users of `getNames()` expect to modify the result. If that is not the usual case, then making those users do the copying is generally the better approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response. you are right. and this is what I know too. I am still pondering over the root cause of the abnormal behavior. The code I provide is just a very minute part of the project perhaps something is happening somehow, somewhere.

Comment: @N.Hubert There is no 'abnormal behaviour' here. Java is working as designed. The problem is you. You are assuming the object is passed by value. It isn't.

Comment: As @user207421 says, this is normal. I added some suggestions to my answer as to how the code could be written to avoid the problem you're having.

Comment: @another-dave. Thank you very much! I have finally understood what you were explaining.

Comment: @user207421 thank you ! haha I have stopped dreaming now I guess. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to read about class members first, to understand how it works. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

My advice is to refactor the code in this way:

```
public class NamesStore {

    private static NamesStore sNamesStore = new NamesStore();
    private List<Name> sNames = new ArrayList<>();

    private NamesStore(){}

    public static NamesStore getInstance() {
        return sNamesStore;
    }

    public List<Name> getNames() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sNames);
    }

    public List<Name> getNamesWithout(List<Name> namesToBeRemoved) {
        return sNames.stream().filter(name -> !namesToBeRemoved.contains(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

EXPLANTION ABOUT FILTER METHOD

The method **getNamesWithout(List namesToBeRemoved)** can be written also in this way:

```
public List<Name> getNamesWithout(List<Name> namesToBeRemoved) {
    return sNames.stream().filter(new Predicate<Name>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Name name) {
            return !namesToBeRemoved.contains(name);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The interface Predicate, has a single abstract method (a single method that you have to implement in subclasses). In Java, an interface with a single abstract method is called **functional interface**. When you have to implement a functional interface, you can use [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). What does't mean this: you can omit the boilerplate code and to keep only what is important. In the below picture, the important code is marked in green and the boilerplate code in red.

I hope that my explanation clarifies you what is with that *name* from the lambda expression.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. please Sir, what is "name" in the method getNamesWithout.?

Comment: @N.Hubert about the "name", please see my above explanation.

Comment: thank you very much I learned something new from your response.